# Read sparse array from numpy to chunked dask array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

Having a big 3D NumPy array (with majority of zeros in it) I am trying to convert it into chunked version of sparse array in Dask

```
import sparse
import dask.array as da

input_arr = np.load(...)
chunked_arr = da.from_array(input_arr, (32,32,32)).map_blocks(sparse.COO)
```

AFAIK chunking works but the output array retains all zeros from the input, so that size of `chunked_arr` equals the size of `input_arr`. Is there a way of loading the input while ommiting all the zeros?

Comment: What does this `sparse.COO` do?

Comment: @hpaulj [`sparse.COO`](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2562#issuecomment-318402438) is a sparse representation of a matrix in a form of `(x, y, z, value)`. I'm still playing with it but I hoped it would make each block sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently you're still loading all of the data into a numpy array, so it must fit into memory?

Ideally you would use a storage technology that allowed for sparse storage, or at least random access.  TileDB is an interesting choice today.

Today I would probably store data in HDF5 or Zarr with some appropriate compression to hide the cost of the zeros, then call

```
x = da.from_array(storage, chunks='auto')
x = x.map_partitions(sparse.COO)
```

Just as you have above, but where storage is something that provides random access from disk.

Comment: Thanks for a hint, I'll give it a try!